# Focus() not working in any navigator

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I am simply firing this:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('nombreAsegurado').focus(); }, 0);
```

This is related to a dropdown menu, when the user clicks on the search input, a dropdown menu is displayed, then the user selects an item, the menu disappears and then I want to focus on the input so the user can search in the cathegory that has been selected before in the dropdown menu.

I am working with prototype framework (I hate it). This input is called by an ajax request, does this have something to do with the issue?

Element:

```
        <input type="text" value="Ingrese" size="20" maxlength="60" name="nombreAsegurado" id="nombreAsegurado" style="color: #666666;font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 10px;vertical-align:middle;background: url(${self.monitor.basePath}images/input_bg.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;padding: 2px 4px;" onclick="if(this.value=='Ingrese Asegurado') this.value=''; this.style.border='1px solid #C4C4C4'; DisplayOptions();" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13) buscar_asegurado();" onblur="CloseOptions();">
```

Comment: So there's an element with the id "nombreAsegurado"?

Comment: Exactly, I forgot to paste the HTML. I will edit that. Thanks

Comment: Well a [simple case](http://jsfiddle.net/bbQy9/) seems to work fine for me (in Firefox).  Is it possible that that input element does not exist at the time that the function runs?

Comment: No it is impossible because I click on the input that I want to focus in, to make a dropdown menu appear. Then I select one option from that menu, which dissapears. Then, focus() should point at the input that I have clicked in at first, is it clear? It is a weird behavior, that is why I was thinking about AJAX, because the input is previously loaded by ajax.

Comment: Well I'd make sure that the timeout function is being called and that the "nombreAsegurado" element really exists, using `console.log()` or something.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved, i changed the position of this line:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('nombreAsegurado').focus(); }, 0);
```

and I have put it at the end of my function.